# Multiple listboxes created dynamically with event

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm creating dynamically multiple `listboxes` in `c#` using the `for` loop.
I want to add to each one of them a `SelectionChanged` so that when the selected item changed I display a content based on which `listbox` it is and the item.
But it seems that the event is linked to only the last one:

```
for (int d =0; d<3; d++)
{                   
   //list des attribut
   ListBox lb = new ListBox();
   lb.Width = 200;
   lb.Height = 250;

   for( int i=0; i< names.Length; i++)
   {                                     
       lb.Items.Add(names[i]);       
   }

   listboxes.Add(lb);
   lb.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => LBTest_SelectionChanged(sender, e, d); 
   ResultPalner.Children.Add(lb);
}

public void LBTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
{
   // Do something here according to which listbox it is!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void LBTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
{
   ListBox lst = sender as ListBox;
   if (lst.Name ==  "listBox1")
    {
       // do something here according to..        
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, I added a name to each listbox then used it, I realize that i dont need the variable ( int i ) after all, thank u

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `object sender` in the `LBTest_SelectionChanged` to find out which `ListBox` changed its selection.

```
public void LBTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int i) {
    if(/* sender is listbox 1*/) {
        /* do something */
    } else if (/* sender is listbox 2*/) {
        /* do something else */
    } else ...
}
```

Like

```
public void LBTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int i) {
    if((ListBox)sender.Name == "name1") {
        /* do something */
    } else if ((ListBox)sender.Name == "name2") {
        /* do something else */
    } else ...
}
```

The thing that happens is basically what you do. You want the same function to respond to slection changes of all `ListBoxes`s. That's why it happens.